# ansible, jinja2, nagios host definition with variables for each host

Tags: ansible, jinja2, nagios

I am a bit at loss at how to achieve an ansible playbook that generates nagios config files for a series of hosts, each hosts should have it's own variables set.

I think the issue is that I don't understand how to assign variables value to hosts that are already defined as variables.

here's the very simple ansible playbook main task file I am using

```
- name: Generate the nagios monitoring templates
  template: src={{ item + ".j2" }}
            dest=nagiosdir/{{ item }}
            force=yes
            owner=nagios
            group=nagios
            mode=660
  with_items:
    - linuxservers.cfg
  become: true
```

here's a very simple working ansible vars file I made

```
hosts: [host1_fqdn, host2_fqdn]
```

here's my linuxserver.cfg.j2 template file

```
{% for hosts in hosts %}

define host{
        use                     linux-server            ; Name of host template to use
                            ; This host definition will inherit all variables that are defined
                            ; in (or inherited by) the linux-server host template definition.
        host_name               {{ hosts }}
        alias                   {{ hosts }}
        address                 {{ hosts }}
        action_url               /grafici/index.php/graph?host={{ hosts }}
        }

define service{
        use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       {{ hosts }}
        service_description             Current Load
        check_command           check_by_ssh_remote_load!5.0,4.0,3.0!10.0,6.0,4.0
        notifications_enabled       1
        }
{% endfor %}
```

and this extremely simple for loop works.

on the linuxserver.cfg file I want to be able to add variables to be defined for each host, like so

```
        check_command           check_by_ssh_remote_load!{host1_var1}!{host1_var1}
```

and so forth for each host, as to be able to have a var file in ansible where i define each and every host and for each and every host I should be able to define different values to use withing my nagios check_commands definitions.

what tools available in ansible/jinja2 should I use to achieve that?
I have very little experience so I am quite lost as where to even begin achieving that.

Comment: FWIW. See the role [freebsd_nagios](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/freebsd_nagios). Most of the tasks should be reusable in Linux. Especially the [templates](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-freebsd-nagios/tree/master/templates). See examples in [vars/main.yml](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-freebsd-nagios/blob/master/vars/main.yml).

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.